# Objective C - Declaration Error - please explain

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface Connections()
{
   static Connections *this;
}
@end
```

The above piece of code in .m file throwing compiler error

> Type name does not allow storage class to be specified

at the same time when the

> static

key word is removed it works well - which so obvious. 
Purpose : I want "Connections" instance static and private.

Why is this behavior, please help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You cannot declare class-level variables in Objective-C classes; instead you need to "hide" them in the implementation file, often giving them `static`-scope so they cannot be accessed externally.

Connections.m:

```
#import "Connections.h"

static Connections *_sharedInstance = nil;

@implementation Connections

...

@end
```

And if this is a singleton, you typically define a class-level accessor to create the singleton upon first use:

```
+ (Connections *)sharedInstance
{
    if (_sharedInstance == nil)
    {
        _sharedInstance = [[Connections alloc] init];
    }
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

(and you'll need to add the declaration in the .h file):

```
+ (Connections *)sharedInstance;
```

Comment: meaning objC classes can only take decl. of ivars, is it right ?