# Received memory warning. with ipad camera

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

When i open Camera in my app it works fine, but when i navigate in my app and comes back to camera view and again try to open my camera in iPad, app crashes and gives me "Received memory warning". app working fine in iPhone and this issues is only coming in iPad.

My project was without ARC so i converted my project into ARC in the hope to get good results but still my app crashes on camera after little navigation.
can anybody tell me how to decrease memory space with iPad camera so that my apps stop receiving memory warning.

this is my code for camera

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        imagePicker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        //imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

This is where I get my Image

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker     didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
        [Array removeAllObjects];

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        [array addObject:image];
        image=nil;

}
```

and i have also try to use popOverview for camera but it also didn't work.

In my viewController where I'm calling UIImagePickerController I have used 5 animations, before i was calling animation in viewWillAppear, and app was crashing so i changed Animation calling to ViewDidLoad and camera starting working but only until I navigate to my last view and comes back to open camera again.

Comment: The problem is not the camera. You are probably not discarding the used and unnecessary objects properly.

Comment: Are you using the iOS default camera picker or connecting the camera to a preview layer or e.g. are you processing each video buffer using OpenGL or CoreImage?

Comment: @Desdenova I m using ARC now, so how could i release objects.

Comment: @Markus No bro I m opening camera not using openGL

Comment: I'd start by running `Instruments` and see what's taking too much memory.

Comment: After capturing the image what your are doing? Are u creating too many images in that same view controller?

Comment: @Desdenova, I dont have any idea about Instruments, can you share some tutorial for Instruments.

Comment: @Ganapathy, no I m just saving image in array, thats sit. Problem in ipad camera using too much memory, but as i navigate through my app Memory allocated to my app remains shorten and Camera crashes the app.

Comment: So your saving the images in array right? Update your query with that array.

Comment: Try this one. http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: Have you tried with @autoreleasepool ? It will  control memory up to some instant...

Comment: @Ganapathy, update my query means?

Comment: Update your question with that array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run your app without animation and then try, if it works then you need to improve your animations memory allocation, as animation needs a lot of memory.

Answer (score 3):

I am getting same problem so i do like this.

Set UIImagePickerController as static like this.

```
 static UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;
```

When you get image in this deleget.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info { 
  @autoreleasepool {// to release memory

   // Probelm is you image size. 
   // When you get this image it is vary large.
   // And i hope  you are creating multiple copy's of this image.

   // when you get image in 
   UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    // In last set image as nil
   image = nil;
  }
}
```

Hope this will solve you problem.. :-)

Comment: xcode showing error on static "Type name does not allow storage class to be specified"

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960249/objective-c-declaration-error-please-explain   --> in witch call you declare static  variable mean's in .h or .m. If it is in .h then remove from it and redeclare in .m file

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code.try `UIImagePickerController` with in popover

```
if([UIImagePickerContrller isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
{
        UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        controller.allowsEditing = YES;
        controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        controller.delegate = self;
        UIPopoverController *popController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]  initWithContentViewController:controller];
        popController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(350.0f, 500);
        [popController presentPopoverFromRect: self.button.frame inView:self.button.superview
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft animated:YES]
}
```

Comment: I have already mention in my question that popover not solved my problem. and second in your code you have given UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary as source type?